# start refreshing javascript functions, then stopping them and restart refreshing them

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I will do my best to clearly explain my problem.
So I have made a bunch of javascript functions that display a value and to keep those values up-to-date I need an interval to refresh the functions.

these are the functions in my interval

```
var interval = null; //make global variable for interval

function refresh(){      // create a function that contains all the functions that need to be refreshed so I can pass this function to my setInterval
        g1.refresh(linearScaling(0, 32761 , 0 , 10, readData('IW0')));
        showAnalogText('textonly', 'IW0');
        g2.refresh(linearScaling(0, 32761 , 0 , 10, readData('IW1')));
        showAnalogText('textonly2', 'IW1');
        showDigInputImg('light1', 'IX2.0', '/imgs/lightON.png', '/imgs/lightOFF.png');
        showDigInputImg('light2', 'IX2.1', '/imgs/lightON.png', '/imgs/lightOFF.png');
        showDigInputBool('led1', 'IX2.0', 'radio');
        showDigInputBool('led2', 'IX2.1', 'radio');
        showDigInputBool('boolean1', 'IX2.0', 'bool');
        showDigInputBool('boolean2', 'IX2.1', 'bool');
        showDigInputBool('text1', 'IX2.0', 'text');
        showDigInputBool('text2', 'IX2.1', 'text');
        showDigInputImg('output1', 'QX2.0', '/imgs/lightON.png', '/imgs/lightOFF.png');
        showDigInputImg('output2', 'QX2.1', '/imgs/lightON.png', '/imgs/lightOFF.png');
        }, 1000)
```

so these functions need to be constantly updated, they execute a read request with ajax but I also have write functions and what I want to accomplish, is to stop the interval whenever I execute my write function, so the ajax requests stop and I can perform my write request and when write is done it restarts the interval.

these are my start and stop functions:

```
        function startRefresh(){  //needs to be declared in my library but the function refresh() doesn't exist in library
        if (!interval){
            interval = setInterval(refresh, 1000);
        }
    }

    function stopRefresh(){  

            clearInterval(interval);
            interval = null;
    }
```

I know this works but the problem is i'm building a library so users can re-use my functions for their own use, so the startrefresh and stoprefresh functions will be in the library, but the startrefresh function needs refresh() (containing all those other functions) but refresh can only be declared in the javascript of the HTML page itself (not in the library) because the function refresh contains objects such as g1 and g2 which are created during run-time, so i can't declare refresh() in my library because it contains object that don't exist yet.

Can anyone help me get an easy solution, U may change whatever U want, I just want the most effecient way that a user can put all the functions he needs to refresh in an interval and stop and start the interval when I execute a write, but the stop and startrefresh function need to be in the library, the user isn't supposed to see the start and stopfunction, they are called in my write function.
hope somebody can understand this and help me, I would be very grateful, if you need more explanations i'm happy to give it to you

maybe putting all the functions in some sort of variable and passing that variable to my startrefresh function, would that work?

Peace, Stijn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't use function as argument to `startRefresh`

```
function startRefresh(refresh) {
    if (!interval){
        interval = setInterval(refresh, 1000);
    }
}
```

so you can run the function using anonymous function

```
startRefresh(function() {
   //do stuff to be refreshed
});
```

or in your case you will be able to store refresh function in anonymouse function too

```
startRefresh(function(){
    g1.refresh(linearScaling(0, 32761 , 0 , 10, readData('IW0')));
    showAnalogText('textonly', 'IW0');
    g2.refresh(linearScaling(0, 32761 , 0 , 10, readData('IW1')));
    showAnalogText('textonly2', 'IW1');
    showDigInputImg('light1', 'IX2.0', '/imgs/lightON.png', '/imgs/lightOFF.png');
    showDigInputImg('light2', 'IX2.1', '/imgs/lightON.png', '/imgs/lightOFF.png');
    showDigInputBool('led1', 'IX2.0', 'radio');
    showDigInputBool('led2', 'IX2.1', 'radio');
    showDigInputBool('boolean1', 'IX2.0', 'bool');
    showDigInputBool('boolean2', 'IX2.1', 'bool');
    showDigInputBool('text1', 'IX2.0', 'text');
    showDigInputBool('text2', 'IX2.1', 'text');
    showDigInputImg('output1', 'QX2.0', '/imgs/lightON.png', '/imgs/lightOFF.png');
    showDigInputImg('output2', 'QX2.1', '/imgs/lightON.png', '/imgs/lightOFF.png');
    }, 1000)
});
```

**UPDATE**

```
function makeStartRefresher(refresh) {
    return function() {
        if (!interval){
            interval = setInterval(refresh, 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

and you can use this function using:

```
var startRefresh = makeStartRefresher(function() {
    g1.refresh(linearScaling(0, 32761 , 0 , 10, readData('IW0')));
    showAnalogText('textonly', 'IW0');
    g2.refresh(linearScaling(0, 32761 , 0 , 10, readData('IW1')));
    showAnalogText('textonly2', 'IW1');
    showDigInputImg('light1', 'IX2.0', '/imgs/lightON.png', '/imgs/lightOFF.png');
    showDigInputImg('light2', 'IX2.1', '/imgs/lightON.png', '/imgs/lightOFF.png');
    showDigInputBool('led1', 'IX2.0', 'radio');
    showDigInputBool('led2', 'IX2.1', 'radio');
    showDigInputBool('boolean1', 'IX2.0', 'bool');
    showDigInputBool('boolean2', 'IX2.1', 'bool');
    showDigInputBool('text1', 'IX2.0', 'text');
    showDigInputBool('text2', 'IX2.1', 'text');
    showDigInputImg('output1', 'QX2.0', '/imgs/lightON.png', '/imgs/lightOFF.png');
    showDigInputImg('output2', 'QX2.1', '/imgs/lightON.png', '/imgs/lightOFF.png');
    }, 1000)
});
```

Comment: this makes sense but the problem is, I have a write function in my library which gets called when a button is clicked, this is my write function '  function writeData(adres, value){
   
   stopRefresh();
   var url = getUrl();
   $.get(url + '/WRITEPI?ADR1=' + adres + '&VALUE1=' + value + '&FORMAT1=%d', function(data){ });
   startRefresh(refresh);
  }'
so the problem is when writedata is called, startrefresh will eventually be called but i can't implement it like you said because in the library elements like g1 and g2 don't exist.
i'm sorry if u can't understand, it's hard for me to explain.

Comment: you can use higher order function for this, I'll update the answer.

Comment: wow nice I understand, thanks a lot, but I still have a question, when I create the variable 'startrefresh' the function that is returned by 'makeStartRefresher', when is this executed? does it get called when the variable is created? and is it possible to pass this variable to a function (i.e. my write function) and execute the variable within that function? I want this so that I can pass it whenever I execute a write (which has to stop and restart the interval) so I don't have to redefine the whole startrefresh variable within my write function

Comment: In order to execute `startRefresh` function you need to do the same as with normal function `startRefresh()` and you can pass both variables and functions to other function in javascript.